# Function definition in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have 2 samples problems ,I can't solved them

the first

```
abss :: Int->Int
abss x 
        | x<0           =x
        | otherwise     =-x
```

The second

```
headd ::[a]->a
headd [x,_] = x
```

Comment: Just as a side note, you didn't explain what you were trying to accomplish or what the problems you are facing are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So let me try:

```
abss :: Int->Int
abss x 
        | x<0           =x
        | otherwise     = -x
```

the way you wrote it Haskell would assume the operator `=-` in there - you need the space ;)

```
headd ::[a]->a
headd (x:_) = x
```

and here you want your `head` version to look at the first element of a non-empty list (those have the form `x:rest`.
`[x,_]` will only match lists like `[1,2]`, "ab", ... but not `[1,2,3]`, "abc", ..

BTW: I assume you want this function to be partial (just like `head` is) - you can get rid of the compiler warning with:

```
headd ::[a]->a
headd [] = error "no head on empty list"
headd (x:_) = x
```

if you want